# Swift charts - highlight center point

Tags: swift, charts

I am using https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts for creating a chart.
After user scrolls the chart, I wanted to get the data point closest to the middle of the chart:

```
        let currentMinX = self.chartView.lowestVisibleX
        let currentMaxX = self.chartView.highestVisibleX
        let midX = currentMinX + (currentMaxX - currentMinX)/2

        let currentMinY = self.chartView.chartYMin // y is not scrollable, so I can use it
        let currentMaxY = self.chartView.chartYMax
        let midY = currentMinY + (currentMaxY - currentMinY)/2

        let midPoint = CGPoint(x: midX, y: midY)

        let closestPoint = chartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(midPoint)
        print("\(closestPoint?.x ?? 0)-\(closestPoint?.y ?? 0)")
```

Unfortunately closestPoint is the closest to the lower-left corner of the visible area, not the one closest to the middle. Why is that?
Debugging movie: https://youtu.be/YTYqt5o6ifQ

EDIT:
Apparently the transformer was returning the wrong value:
I've fixed it by changing the Transformer's method:

```
 @objc open func valueForTouchPoint(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat) -> CGPoint
    {
        return CGPoint(x: x, y: y)//CGPoint(x: x, y: y).applying(pixelToValueMatrix)
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getHighlightByTouchPoint` expects the point in view coordinate system. (same as `valueForTouchPoint`) And your `(midX, midY)` point is in chart coordinate system. Probably that is the main reason why you get incorrect result. If so, you can replace your code with this:

```
    // if you have any additional insets, for chart area in the view, 
    // change calculation of this point to make it point to the middle of the chart area
    let midPoint = CGPoint(x: self.chartView.bounds.midX, y: self.chartView.bounds.midY) 
    let closestPoint = chartView.getHighlightByTouchPoint(midPoint)
```

**Upd:** Replaced `frame` with `bounds` for more correct implementation in different situations